# Use redirect instead of forward on <welcome-file>

Tags: jsf, redirect, seo, web.xml, welcome-file

In my web.xml file, I configured:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

It means, when I type a URL `www.domain.com`, `index.xhtml` file is used to render. But when I type `www.domain.com/index.xhtml`, the result is the same.
is it called duplicated content?
This is no problem for my project but a big problem for SEO.
How can I redirect to `www.domain.com/index.xhtml` page when typing URL `www.domain.com` instead of letting it perform a forward?

Comment: Request to `www.domain.com/index.xhtml` is the same because `index.xhtml` is probably in your webapps folder which is public.

Comment: your are right. But i just want to avoid duplicated content. how to do that. Do you mean, now i have to hide index.xhtml and edit web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An URL is marked duplicate content when there's another URL on the same domain which returns **exactly** the same response. And yes, you should definitely worry about this if SEO is important.

Easiest way to fix this is to provide a so-called canonical URL in the head of `index.xhtml`. This should represent the URL of preference, which is in your particular case apparently the one with the filename:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/index.xhtml" />
```

This way the `http://www.domain.com` will be indexed as `http://www.domain.com/index.xhtml`. and not cause duplicate content anymore. However, this will not stop endusers being able to bookmark/share different URLs anyway.

Another way is to configure a HTTP 301 redirect to the URL of preference. It's very important to understand that the origin of a 302 redirect is still indexed by searchbots, but the origin of a 301 redirect not, only the target page is indexed. If you would be using a 302 as by default used by `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`, then you would still end up having duplicate content because the both URLs are still indexed.

Here's a kickoff example of such a filter. Just map it on `/index.xhtml` and perform a 301 redirect when the URI doesn't equal the desired path.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = IndexFilter.PATH)
public class IndexFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String PATH = "/index.xhtml";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String uri = request.getContextPath() + PATH;

        if (!request.getRequestURI().equals(uri)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY); // 301
            response.setHeader("Location", uri);
            response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    // init() and destroy() can be NOOP.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate content, design a Filter with URL patter `/*`. If user on root domain than redirect to `index.xhtml` URL.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "IndexFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class IndexFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    String requestURL = request.getRequestURI().toString();
    if (request.getServletPath().equals("/index.xhtml") &&
                !requestURL.contains("index.xhtml")) {
        response.sendRedirect("http://" + req.getServerName() + ":"
                + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()
                +"/index.xhtml");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: The `sendRedirect()` does a 302, not a 301. Remainder of filter's code is also not exciting, while it does its job, it's clearly written by a starter and several things can be done more clean.

Comment: Thanks @Masud but i want to ask more. Is that phenomenon called duplicated content?

Comment: I don't think he's able to tell something about SEO the right way because he already isn't redirecting with 301 in first place.